# Get data when date is equal to or greater than 90 days ago

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I wonder if anyone here can help with a BigQuery piece I am working on.
I'm trying to pull the date, email and last interaction time from a dataset when the last interaction time is equal to or greater than 90 days ago.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  date,
  user_email,
  DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(gmail.last_interaction_time) AS Last_Interaction_Date,
  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -90 DAY) AS Days_ago
FROM
  `bqadminreporting.adminlogtracking.usage`
WHERE
  'Last_Interaction_Date' >= 'Days_ago'
```

However, I run into the following error:

> DATE value is out of allowed range: from 0001-01-01 to 9999-12-31

As far as I can see, it makes sense - so not entirely sure why its throwing out an error?

Comment: Could you paste an example of input data and expected output?

Comment: Does it say which column that is?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some inconsistent values (data) in filed `gmail.last_interaction_time`, which you need to handle to avoid error.

Moreover above query will not work as per your expected WHERE conditions, you should use following query to get expected output.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
  date,
  user_email,
  DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(gmail.last_interaction_time) AS Last_Interaction_Date,
  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -90 DAY) AS Days_ago
FROM
  `bqadminreporting.adminlogtracking.usage`)
WHERE
  Last_Interaction_Date >= Days_ago
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your problem is `DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE()`.  Without sample data, it is not really possible to determine what the issue is.

However, you don't need to convert to a date to do this.  You can do all the work in the Unix seconds space:

```
select u.*
from `bqadminreporting.adminlogtracking.usage` u
where gmail.last_interaction_time >= unix_seconds(timestamp(current_date)) - 90 * 60 * 60 * 24
```

Note that I suspect that the issue is that `last_interaction_time` is really measured in milliseconds or microseconds or some other unit.  This will prevent your error, but it might not do what you want.

Comment: Ahh, I think you may be onto something here.   
The date comes out as:   
    1611657308
Before I do anything with it

Comment: @SL8t7 . . . That looks like seconds since 1970.  This should work as should your original code.